# Conectarse a SSH con python con librerías estándar

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, python-2.x

estoy intentando conectarme a un router cisco ios desde un servidor en el que no puedo instalar ninguna librería por falta de permisos los cuales no puedo pedir, la versión de python es la 2.6 y tampoco puedo actualizarla, intente conectarme con telnet pero esta bloqueado y entonces estuve buscando como conectarse con ssh con librerías estándar, pero solo encuentro cosas relacionadas a `netmiko` y `paramiko`.

Como puedo conectarme a ssh desde python 2 con librerias estándar?

Comment: Hola Diego, no se exactamente que necesitas, pero en última instancia si no puedes instalar nada podrías usar SSH vía subprocess.

Comment: @FJSevilla Mi cliente quiere poder conectarse a sus routers desde un servidor con SSH, tambien habia pensado en usar subprocess, pero me dijo que no.